# Trying to commit XCode project to Github, but Github sees legit source tree as submodule

Tags: xcode, git, github

I'm trying to archive an XCode source tree in Github.  Here's my current process for doing so:

1. Go to Github and create the private repository that will contain the code.  Tell Github that it's an Objective-C application (so it creates the right .gitignore file).
2. git clone github@github.com:example-org/xcode-repo
3. cd xcode-repo
4. unzip ~/xcode-project.zip
5. git add .
6. git commit -m 'initial archival import'
7. git push
8. Visit github.com for the repository.
9. Observe that the directory created by the unzip command now appears as a submodule.

I observe that the subdirectory referenced above *does not* contain a subordinate `.git` directory.  I can't find any signal when searching for this on Google, Bing, or Stack Overflow.  Anyone experience this before, and if so, what did you do to resolve the issue?

Thanks for any help folks can offer.

**UPDATE**: I thought I'd mentioned this earlier, but I either erased it for some reason, or just plain forgot.  Apologies for my oversight!  I am on a Linux computer, attempting to archive source code developed before I arrived on this project.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier if you reverse the process. Instead of creating a repository in GitHub and cloning it, create your Xcode project first. When you create the project, there's a checkbox to create a local git repository.

[image]

Select that checkbox. After creating the project, put the project on GitHub.

If you're using Xcode 9, you can add your Xcode project to GitHub without leaving Xcode. Go to the source control navigator, select the Remotes folder, right-click, and choose Create Remote on GitHub. You can see screenshots and more detailed information in the following Stack Overflow question:

[How to connect Xcode 9 and GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48794960/how-to-connect-xcode-9-and-github/48795374)

And the following article:

[Xcode 9: Adding Your Project to GitHub](http://meandmark.com/blog/2018/02/xcode-9-adding-your-project-to-github/)

**UPDATE**

Since you're not on a Mac and don't have access to Xcode, you would be better off starting with Step 4. Unzip the Xcode project. Call git init to create a local repository for the Xcode project. Then go to GitHub, create the remote repository, and follow the instructions GitHub gives you to get the local repository on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks; alas, this won't work as I'm not using a Mac, much less XCode.  I thought I'd stated this, but apparently not.  I'll edit the question accordingly.  Apologies for my oversight!