# Why cant i commit to GitHub?

Tags: xcode, github, version-control

Hi i have set up my GitHub Account and linked my Xcode to it under preferences -> Accounts. So i created a repository on GitHub and wanted to upload my project but there was no option to do so. What am i missing ? 
I tried to follow this [Tutorial](https://blog.chrishannah.me/putting-your-xcode-project-on-github-the-easy-way/) but i didn't get the shown dropdown Menu.

[SourceControl Drop Down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07GKm.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect Xcode 9 and GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48794960/how-to-connect-xcode-9-and-github)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find out how to push it to a GitHub repository, it's mean that you haven't ticked the box "Create a repository on mac" at the creation of your project.

So if it's true, you have to do:
1. Use the terminal and create the repository on your mac
2. After that, you will see a complete menu in Xcode Source Control.

For step 1: follow the beginning of [this tutorial](http://belencruz.com/en/2014/12/create-a-git-repository-from-an-existing-xcode-project/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a menu under Xcode -> Preferences-> Source Control

and you have to tick a box called "Enable Source Control"

Please find a screenshot.
[Enable Github repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPEJV.png)

Comment: Thanks but this checkbox was already checked. I think the commit was saved on my mac and i have to find out how to push it to a gihtub repository.