# How to add xcode project to github repository on xcode 12

Tags: swift, github, xcode12

i wanted to add my project to git but i tapped something on source control by mistake. All tutorials are showing buttons that i don't have in xcode 12. how can i add my project to git? [this is source control after changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWqEr.png)

Comment: Do it via terminal. https://codewithchris.com/github-tutorial/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect Xcode 9 and GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48794960/how-to-connect-xcode-9-and-github)

Comment: @StefanOvomate 's answer solved my problem. thanks!

Comment: Mark the comment as useful. Thanks

Comment: @StefanOvomate sorry but how to do it?

Comment: Check next to the comment is an upvote. Maybe it is not possible because your reputation is 1.

Comment: ohh sorry i can's see it. but thank u